# How to avoid same content and keyword for multiple pages and focus on master page only

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-crawlers, google-index

Hello Good morning all,

Hope all doing well, i am in a triangular situation for my multiple details pages, i want some idea how i can avoid google to not to crawl my details page and to crowl its container page which contains 90% same keyword, meta and url. For an example i have one page which is a master page of multiple categories here http://www.estatemarker.com/ahmedabad/industrial-properties.html it contains multiple categories when i open a category it let us to another page http://www.estatemarker.com/ahmedabad/industrial-warehouse.html which is subcategory now this subcategory has area vise listings of multiple pages this pages are same as this subcategory page but these contains listing of area only and this page has actual listing posted by brokers, now problem is i want to focus google on this page area vise page only but this page contains 50 more listing which opens a details page and details page contains 90% of same keyword and other SEO stuffs per the area vise page  page. I need a guidance how i should avoid google to not to crawl this details page and area vise page instead.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give canonical tag or can use

Robot.txt codes like

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *?dir=*
Disallow: *&order=*
Disallow: *?price=*
```

to face such problems.
http://www.goinflow.com/duplicate-content-ecommerce-seo/